# Implementation of a FREE web filter

Tags: web-browser, access-control

I just want some advice for the implementation of a web filter for a school network. Just want to block some contents and url. A free tool should be fine I guess. 
Any recommendations?
Thanks!

Comment: We're going to need a LOT more information. Size, throughput, do you want to host the filter or use an offsite service? Is this to a server that blocks traffic, or something to install on individual computers?

Comment: +1 to @schroeder.  Additionally, "product recommendation" queries are generally off-topic for all StackExchange sites.  If you could generalize your question to ask about what methods are available to accomplish a particular goal, or if you want to ask about the security posture of one particular implementation, that would be acceptable.  As it is, the question is currently very vague and unanswerable *and* it falls outside of the scope defined in our [faq].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Squid](http://www.squid-cache.org/)/[Squidguard](http://www.squidguard.org/) is kind of the de facto standard for this kind of thing. It's free and runs on Linux. This can work if your intent is to filter all traffic on the border of your network instead of installing a filter on each machine.